# Print "foo" when I hit the enter key Haskell

Tags: haskell

First,  I wanted to write a program in Haskell that would start printing my girlfriend's name when I hit the 's' key and then stop when I hit the 's' key again.  But I could not understand how to write such a program.

Instead I tried to write a program(had help from fellow redditers) that would print 'foo' when I hit the enter key but it seems 'foo' does not want to print.  Why is that?

```
{-# language NumDecimals #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Concurrent.Async (concurrently_)

keyWatcher :: MVar () -> IO ()
keyWatcher latch = forever (do _ <- getLine
                               _ <- takeMVar latch
                               _ <- getLine
                               putMVar latch())

loop :: MVar () -> IO ()
loop latch = forever (do swapMVar latch ()
                         threadDelay 1e6
                         putStrLn "Marika Boo!!!")

main :: IO ()
main = do latch <- newMVar ()
          concurrently_ (loop latch) (keyWatcher latch)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129802/discussion-on-question-by-matthew-carland-print-foo-when-i-hit-the-enter-key-h).

Comment: @BhargavRao The moved comments include the ones which explain why this question falls under "cannot be reproduced". To avoid confusion for future readers, [here is a link to them](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34418593#34418593).